# How can I build a file/dir path map in PHP?

Tags: php, path, hashmap, associative-array

I'm a Frontend developer and I've decided to expand my knowledge learning PHP. I'm still learning the syntax / ways of accomplishing stuff so please bear with me.

As I began working on my first PHP project I realised that I needed to create a path map just to keep things clean and DRY.

This is what my php file structure looks like by now:

[image]

That is easy to represent using a JSON like data structure, but I've found a embarrassing hard time trying to achieve that using PHP data types ( I'm still learning the syntax / ways of doing things ).

I've been reading a bit and I decided to use some associative arrays,
I've come up with this solution, which works but I wanted to check if a simpler solution is possible. ( I'm aiming to learn the best practices of PHP )

See:

```
$paths = array(
    'dirs' => array(
        'base' => '/php/'
    )
);

$paths['dirs']['common'] = $paths['dirs']['base'] . 'common/';
$paths['dirs']['home'] = $paths['dirs']['base'] . 'home/';

$paths['files'] = array(
    'home' => $paths['dirs']['home'] . 'home.php',
    'header' => $paths['dirs']['common'] . 'header.php',
    'scripts' => $paths['dirs']['common'] . 'scripts.php',
    'footer' => $paths['dirs']['common'] . 'footer.php',
    'core' => $paths['dirs']['base'] . 'core.php',
    'business-variables' => $paths['dirs']['base'] . 'business-variables.php'
);
```

Am I doing bad practices here?

Is there a better / simpler / standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with files - the best and easiest way is use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php). In this case each file will be object and you can use his methods. Here a small example:

```
// or '/php/' in your case
$path = '/';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
    if ($file->isDot()) continue;

    if ($file->isDir()) {
        print $file->getFilename() . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can't just read the folder structure using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)...

For readability I'd do something like this:

```
class FileStructure {
    const BASE = '/php/';
    const COMMON = 'common/%s';
    const HOME = 'home/%s';

    public function Paths(){
       return array(
           'home' => $this->Home('home.php'),
           'header' => $this->Common('header.php')
       );
    }

    private function Common($file = null){
       return sprintf(static::BASE.static::COMMON, $file);
    }

    private function Home($file = null){
       return sprintf(static::BASE.static::HOME, $file);
    }
}
```